# How to call 3 different Api's based on a onChange() function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
I need to call 3 different API's with different parameter based on a onChange function.

www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=chicken_breast
www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Seafood
www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?a=Canadian
```

I have three dropdowns Category, Area and Ingredients and I do have to call three different api which actually has the same api endpoint with 3 different paramaters.

If I choose Category dropdown I have to call:
[www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Seafood](http://www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Seafood)

If I choose Area dropdown I have to call:
[www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?a=Canadian](http://www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?a=Canadian)

If I choose Ingredients dropdown I have to call:
[www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=chicken_breast](http://www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=chicken_breast)

HTML:

```
     <div class="dropdown">
         <select name="Categories" (change)="onCategorySelected($event)" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Categories</option>
            <option *ngFor="let foodName of foodTypeValue" [value]="foodName">{{foodName}}</option>
        </select>
         <select name="Area" (change)="onCategorySelected($event)" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Area</option>
            <option *ngFor="let areaName of loadArea" [value]="areaName.strArea">{{areaName.strArea}}</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Ingredients" (change)="onCategorySelected($event)"
            class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Ingredients</option>
            <option *ngFor="let ingredientsName of ingredientsList" [value]="ingredientsName">
                {{ingredientsName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Is there Any feasible way that I can handle this through rxjs operator or any other way ?

Comment: I don't know about this API, but wouldn't it be possible to have one API call to `http://www.foods.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Seafood&a=Canadian&i=chicken_breast` ? Seeing that filter.php is called in all three cases and only the parameters change.

Comment: But I need to show category value when category got selected, same as like I need to show for area and Ingredient as I said I do have three dropdown, I could have done it by calling three different function for three category, area and Ingredient but I thought there might be a way we can achieve this with single function for three dropdowns

Comment: Well, you can just use one function and then through parameters let the function know, which select the call comes from. For example: `onCategorySelected($event, "categories")` for the categories select. Then within the function you check what the string is and adjust the query of the API call accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a second parameter, which holds the query field name.

```
<div class="dropdown">
         <select name="Categories" (change)="onCategorySelected($event, 'c')" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Categories</option>
            <option *ngFor="let foodName of foodTypeValue" [value]="foodName">{{foodName}}</option>
        </select>
         <select name="Area" (change)="onCategorySelected($event, 'a')" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Area</option>
            <option *ngFor="let areaName of loadArea" [value]="areaName.strArea">{{areaName.strArea}}</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Ingredients" (change)="onCategorySelected($event, 'i')"
            class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Ingredients</option>
            <option *ngFor="let ingredientsName of ingredientsList" [value]="ingredientsName">
                {{ingredientsName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>


onCategorySelected(event, queryFieldname) {
  // do your request using queryFieldname to build the url
}
```

---

Edit:

```
loadFilterDetails(
    name: string, // fix the order of the params
    queryfield: string,
  ): Observable<{ meals: Filter[] }> {
    return this.http
      .get<{ meals: Filter[] }>(
        this.recipies.filterDetails + `?${queryfield}=${name}` // use string literals
      )
      .pipe(
        tap((respones) => {
          this.getFilterDetails = respones?.meals;
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but how can I pass the parameter in the Service, since I'm passing the queryFieldname in the TS how can I dynamically change the parameter in service ?

Comment: I have added  the service and TS changes, if that helps you

Comment: See inline comments in my edit

Comment: I have got it right as like it this.recipies.filterDetails + queryfield + '=' + name

Comment: Sure, your solution seems more precise, I'll use them, Thanks